# Make Tar + gzip ignore directory paths

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible, when making a tar + gzip through the 'tar c ...' command, to have the relative paths will be ignored upon expanding?

For example,

```
tar cvf test.tgz foo ../../files/bar
```

And then expanding the test.tgz with

```
tar xvf test.tgz
```

gives a directory containing:

```
foo files/bar
```

I want the directory to contain the files:

```
foo bar
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This question belong to superuser.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all the paths begin with the same initial list of directories then you can use e.g. `tar cvf test.tgz -C ../.. other/dir`.  Beware that the shell won't expand wildcards in pathnames "properly" however because `-C` asks `tar` to change directory.

Otherwise, the only way I've ever come up with is to make a temporary directory filled with appropriate symlinks and use the `-h` option to dereference through symlinks.  Of course that won't work if some of the files you want to store are actually symlinks themselves.